# Set functionTimeout using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

I need to add below property to my host.json file for azure function. Is it possible to add the property using terraform or by passing it using app_setting?

```
{
    "functionTimeout": "00:10:00"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**azurerm_app_configuration**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_configuration) to add the configuration values in an Azure App Service. And [**azurerm_app_configuration_key**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_configuration_key) is used to add the **key-value** pair in an Azure App Service using terraform.

You can use the below **key-value** pair for adding the **timeout values** in Azure

```
key : AzureFunctionsJobHost__functionTimeout 
Value : 00:10:00
```

#### Example

> Note:
> **App Configuration Keys are provisioned using a Data Plane API which requires the role `App Configuration Data Owner` on either the App Configuration or a parent scope (such as the Resource Group/Subscription).**

```json
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "example-location"
}

resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "appconf" {
  name                = "appConf1"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
}

## Adding the App Configuration Data Owner role
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "appconf_dataowner" {
  scope                = azurerm_app_configuration.appconf.id
  role_definition_name = "App Configuration Data Owner"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
}


## Adding the App Settings config values
resource "azurerm_app_configuration_key" "test" {
  configuration_store_id = azurerm_app_configuration.appconf.id
  key                    = "<Your host.json timeout key "AzureFunctionsJobHost__functionTimeout">"
  label                  = "somelabel"
  value                  = "<Your timeout value "00:10:00">"

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_role_assignment.appconf_dataowner
  ]
}
```

Refer [blog](https://truestorydavestorey.medium.com/creating-app-configuration-services-and-config-values-in-azure-using-terraform-c8ec7165aaf2) for adding multiple key-value pair.